# cygwin sshd service not starting on windows 2003

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

Hi! I get following error when tried to start the Cygwin `sshd` Windows service:

```sh
$ cygrunsrv.exe -S sshd
cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: QueryServiceStatus:  Win32 error 1062:
The service has not been started.
```

I used `ssh-host-config` to install the service with privilege separation. The script created two users: `sshd` and `sshd_server`.

Comment: You would have more luck with this on serverfault.com

Comment: Another location to get information to resolve this is on http://cygwin.com

Answer (score 3):

The following solved this issue for me:

Add the "Full Control" permission for the `SYSTEM` user to the following directories:

```
C:\Cygwin
C:\Cygwin\var
C:\Cygwin\var\log
```

If it still doesn't help then, try running `ssh-host-config -y` and retry `cygrunsrv -S sshd`.

Also, I actually uninstalled the `sshd` service by issuing `cygrunsrv -R sshd` prior to retrying and only after that running `ssh-host-config -y`.

(I found the solution at http://www.noah.org/wiki/Sshd_on_Windows)